# Looping with Summation of Fields and dateTime as a counter SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, loops

I have a 3 fields ( ID, Price, Date )
and it looks like this..

```
|ID|  |Price|    |           Date      |
--------------------------------------------
|001|  |150.00|  | 2007-01-01 11:48:18.000 |
|002|  |150.00|  | 2007-01-01 15:57:19.000 |
|003|  |150.00|  | 2007-01-02 13:26:12.000 |
|004|  |150.00|  | 2007-01-03 10:31:14.000 |
```

etc etc

and I need to display the TOTAL AMOUNT of sales for EACH DAY for a certain period of time. 
So when I put January 1 to January 6...
it should be

```
|   Days     |    Total Sales |
-------------------------------
| January 1  | --some amount  |
| January 2  | --some amount  |
| January 3  | --some amount  |
| January 4  | --some amount  |
| January 5  | --some amount  |
| January 6  | --some amount  |
```

I just cant figure it out and Im stuck with this code :)  ...

```
DECLARE @StartDate dateTime,@EndDate dateTime, @TotalSales integer

SET @StartDate = '2007-01-02 11:41:19.000' 
SET @EndDate = '2007-01-02 11:46:06.000'
SET @TotalSales = 0

while ( @StartDate = '2007-01-02 11:41:19.000' )
BEGIN

--Some codes

END
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop, use set operations whenever possible:

```
DECLARE @StartDate dateTime,@EndDate dateTime

SET @StartDate = convert(DateTime,'2007-01-01 11:41:19.000',102)
SET @EndDate = convert(DateTime,'2007-01-04 11:46:06.000',102) 

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ID,Price,[Date]  
    FROM Sales
    WHERE [Date] Between @StartDate AND @EndDate
)
SELECT DATENAME( month ,[Date] ) + ' ' + DATENAME( day ,[Date] ) AS Days
     , SUM(Price)AS 'Total Sales'
FROM CTE 
GROUP BY DATENAME( month ,[Date] ) + ' ' + DATENAME( day ,[Date] )
```

[**SQL-Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52b04/19/0)

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Tim Schmelter's solution except that it handles for days that do not have any sales data:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME
SELECT @StartDate = '01-01-2007', @EndDate = '01-06-2007'

;WITH DateRange ([Date]) AS
(
    SELECT 
      @StartDate [Date]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date]) [Date] 
    FROM 
      DateRange 
    WHERE 
      [Date] < @EndDate
)


SELECT 
  DATENAME(MONTH, d.[Date]) + ' ' + DATENAME(DAY, d.[Date]) AS Days,
  SUM(ISNULL(Price, 0)) AS [Total Sales]
FROM 
  DateRange d
LEFT JOIN 
  Sales s 
ON 
  d.[Date] = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, s.[Date]), 0)
GROUP BY 
  DATENAME(MONTH, d.[Date]) + ' ' + DATENAME(DAY, d.[Date])
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/21a11/1)